# How to print SUM, and AVG SQL values with JDBC?

Tags: oracle, jsp, jdbc

Okay, I am trying to do print the results of a SUM and AVG function using JDBC.  So basically, it's not working.  What am I doing wrong?

```
   <table border="1">
     <tr><th>Total Homes Sold</th><th>Total Sales Amount</th><th>Averages Price Per Home</th></tr>    

       <% rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(home_ID) FROM home");%>
       <% rset1 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(purchase_Price) FROM home");%>          
       <% rset2 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT AVG(purchase_Price) FROM home");%>

       <tr>
         <td><%= rset.getString(1) %></td>
         <td><%= rset1.getString(1) %></td>
         <td><%= rset2.getString(1) %></td>
      </tr>

   </table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? no values show up? errors? exceptions? (btw, you could do those three queries in only one select)

Comment: Yeah, I get an error message that states:root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is closed

Comment: Also, how could I put it into one statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
   <tr>
   <% rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(home_ID) FROM home");%>
     <td><%= rset.getString(1) %></td>
   <% rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(purchase_Price) FROM home");%>          
     <td><%= rset.getString(1) %></td>
   <% rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT AVG(purchase_Price) FROM home");%>
     <td><%= rset.getString(1) %></td>
  </tr>
```

Or better:

```
   <tr>
   <% rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(home_ID), SUM(purchase_Price), AVG(purchase_Price) FROM home");%>
     <td><%= rset.getString(1) %></td>
     <td><%= rset.getString(2) %></td>
     <td><%= rset.getString(3) %></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Okay, so I incorporated: <% rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(home_ID), SUM(purchase_Price), AVG(purchase_Price) FROM home");%> <% while (rset.next()) { %> <tr> <td><%= rset.getString(1) %></td> <td><%= rset.getString(2) %></td> <td><%= rset.getString(3) %></td> </tr> <% } %> The only problem now is that it parses but the results are wrong. Total homes sole is: 0 while the other two are NULL? What the . . . any ideas? When I enter the statements by command line into my SQL*Plus database it works; why doesnt it work with the JDBC?

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that you need to call *next()* on the result set (after *executeQuery()*) to retrieve the first row of the result set (even though there's just one row).

It you don't do it, no row is available and calling *getString()* causes the "ResultSet is closed" error.

Comment: Okay, so I incorporated: <% rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(home_ID), SUM(purchase_Price), AVG(purchase_Price) FROM home");%>
   <% while (rset.next()) { %>
      <tr>
         <td><%= rset.getString(1) %></td>
         <td><%= rset.getString(2) %></td>
         <td><%= rset.getString(3) %></td>
    </tr> 
    <% } %>  The only problem now is that it parses but the results are wrong.  Total homes sole is: 0 while the other two are NULL?  What the . . . any ideas?  When I enter the statements by command line into my SQL*Plus database it works; why doesnt it work with the JDBC?

Comment: The result 0, NULL, NULL is the expected result if your table has no rows. Are you sure that the table contains any data? Have you inserted the data from SQL*plus and forgotten to commit it? Is there some kind of row level security in place that's not properly initialized when accessing from your web server?

Comment: Yeah it looks like we many be having some problems with our database server. . . I will look into it.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Okay, the whole 0, NULL, NULL, thing was a Oracle server error.  Whew, I thought I was crazy --no more than usual anyway :) Thanks for your help!